# How is a '\b' character stored in a string in python"?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

If I have a string

```
dummy_path = "this is a dummy path\basic"
```

The `\b` character is of course a backspace, so this get printed (and processed by filesystem calls) as

> this is a dummy patasic

([Patasic](https://www.google.de/search?q=patasic), nice name!)

Do I have a chance to detect this situation and warn the user (myself) that the `\` in `dummy_path` should be, for example, either escaped or substituted with a `/`?

Comment: try `print(repr(dummy_path))`

Comment: Editor/IDE syntax highlighting will normally mark these sorts of escape sequences in a highly noticeable way.  Are you using syntax highlighting?  Can it be configured to make these constructs more noticeable to you?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but consider using a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for file paths. `r"dummy\basic"` will interpret the backslash as just a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see for yourself:

```
>>> dummy_path = "this is a dummy path\basic"
>>> dummy_path
'this is a dummy path\x08asic'
```

The `len` function also reflects this:

```
>>> len("a\bc")
3
>>> "a\bc"
'a\x08c'
>>> print("a\bc")
c
```

as does the `in` operator with two strings as arguments:

```
>>> "\b" in "a\bc"
True
```

How it is *displayed* is entirely dependent on your output device. Most terminals will print each character one after the other. The `\b`, instead of being visible, simply repositions the cursor one position to the left, at which point the `a` overwrites the previously written `h`.

Notably, this is how a man page displays bold text. Man pages (which are on-screen renderings of `*roff` code) use letter-backspace-letter sequences to indicate a letter should be displayed in bold face. The metaphor comes from typewriters: to type a letter in bold, you type it once, backspace, then type it again over the first one. Similarly, underlining can be represented as letter-backspace-underscore.

Comment: Use `repr` (which is what my example, displaying the value in the interactive shell, demonstrates implicitly). `dummy_path` is a string value, while `repr(dummy_path)` returns a string that *represents* a string value, specifically with otherwise unprintable characters replaced with a `\x??` representation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is just missing a small part regarding how can I detect programmatically the situation, which I suppose it's simply `if "\b" in dummy_path:`

Comment: That's right. The `in` operator, when both arguments are strings, behaves a little bit differently; it returns True if the first argument is a *substring* of the second, rather than if the first argument is an *element* of the second.