# Checking backslashes are correctly escaped in a path string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, escaping

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253949/how-is-a-b-character-stored-in-a-string-in-python), I was wondering if the function below is good enough for checking no accidental sequence backslash-character has been inputted in a path causing a "special character" to be generated. To be more clear, `\b` is a backspace, and `\` followed by a number originates some ascii character code. I want to avoid that. There are also sequences like `\d` that have no special meaning, and apparently in that case the `\` is escaped automatically. I am not worried about that. Here is my function:

```
def checkPathString(dir):
    slash = False
    for c in repr(dir):
        if c == '\\':
            slash = not slash
        else:
            if slash:
                raise ValueError('Path contains unescaped \\ characters')
```

It seems to correctly detect `\b` or `\` followed by a number (as the internal representation becomes `\x`*something*). It also made me discover `\f` is a special sequence, also translated into `\x`*something*.

Detected as bad strings:

```
"C:\dummy\bar" #Because of "\b"
"C:\dummy\2000" #Because of "\" followed by a number
```

Detected as good strings:

```
"C:\dummy\\bar" #\d is escaped automatically because is not a special sequence
"C:\dummy\\2000"
```

Comment: would be better to check if string has ASCII-only characters (between 32 and 127)

Comment: What are you actually trying to check? There's no way for the code to tell whether a special character is there by accident or on purpose. If you want to check for the presence of special characters (for whatever definition of "special") just do that.

Comment: @Goyo I edited the question trying to specify better what is the problem I am trying to tackle.

Comment: @Antonio If you mean actual user input (e.g. `path = raw_input('Path:')`) you should not have that problem since escape sequences in user input are ignored. If you mean paths hardcoded in your code as string literals you should be testing the code to check that the path is correct..

Comment: @Goyo The case is for hardcoded path (or variables preconfigured on a python shell), a sort of configuration one does before running the script. Checking path existence is a good approach. It somehow leaves out the case in which those path are used to create directories, there can be weird things happening in that case.

Comment: @Antonio Code creating directories can be tested too.

Comment: @Goyo Sure, I am speaking about more corner cases, for example in which you create a directory (expecting for example to have created 2 levels), you switch to that directory and then you *think* you go back by going to "../..", when in fact you had created only one level because one ```\``` was translated into something else. One can think of several corner cases. I am not saying this is thoughtful programming, but sometimes things need to be prototyped fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can achieve your aim, as, for example, you cannot protect against `\x` prefixes which define ASCII characters, as they're interpreted when entered.

```
>>> "\x61"
'a'
>>> repr("\x61")
"'a'"
```

So for example any detection method will fail, given a subfolder named x61abcde, in case the input string is "C:\dummy\x61abcde"

Furthermore, detection will fail for several combinations of `\` followed by a number, e.g. you have these immediate interpretations: `\61` => `1` or `\72` => `:`

As a side note, regarding the method you propose, I would just check that any character is in the [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Integer_intervals) [32 .. 127] (or [32 .. 255] if you want to support accents)

```
def check_path_string(path):
    if all(31<ord(c)<127 for c in path):
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("path contains non-ascii characters")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I now understand is that there is no safe way to address my problem, as there is no way to detect if the user inputted a sequence "`\x` *number*" (as you pointed out it will be immediately interpreted) in the unfortunate case a subfolder name starts, for example, with `"x61"`.

Comment: yes, but you can handle most cases, so it could be worth it. Thanks for the edit.